# Meteor run is very slow win 10

Tags: windows, reactjs, meteor

When I'm trying to run meteor project it took a lot of time(almost 2 hours and it still off.)
My CPU is used on 39%, RAM - 75%, Disk - 2%. So that's not my machine problem.
I also use react in the project.

I've searched a lot of articles but I can't solve the issue.

Could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What step is taking time ?

Comment: What do you mean ? 
App Booting takes a long time, and hot refresh takes a lot time as well.

Comment: Have you excluded meteor from antivirus scanning. I've found antivirus is the culprit in 99% of cases

Comment: @FredStark No, I have not. But I will try. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to turn off real-time protection from Windows Defender then it's run faster.